# Android use App1 sources in App2 without installing App1 on device

Tags: android, dependencies, project

I'm developping 2 apps that are different only by their names (App1 and App2 for instance) and resources (icons and strings mostly) and some internal behaviours.
I'm trying to use all .java sources files from App1 into App2. But if I import App1's sources in App2's project App1 is also installed on the device upon App2 launching while I'd only like App2 to be installed.
I cannot make App1 a library to import into App2's project since their resources are conflicting!
How could I use App1's .java files inside App2 without copying them and changing their package name one by one and having to remember to modify App1's files when a bug is corrected into App2 or a new feature is added in one app and vice-versa?

Thanks in advance for your help,
Gg.

Comment: So u want to use a project in two apps apart from resources and icon where every things are common? Am i right?

Comment: Yes something like that...
I managed to separate the initial code into a library containing the activities and fragments (and their respective resources) to be reused in every app; I only keep main activity and specific resources in each app as a new project using the library.

Answer (score 0):

Parents can't inherit child classes, same goes for the scenario what you are asking.

What you can do is to create a parent library that will be inherited by both app, and perform changes on the parents library.

Comment: No the app doesn't inherit from the library: it just uses activities, fragments and other classes using agregation but splitting the code into a common library and an app was the trick...
Thanks for your answer.

Comment: You can create a common activity say skeletonActivity and then extend your activity from that. The skeletonActivity will have all the function that is required by both activity.